# PostgreSQL SELECT between records one attribute with conditional assesment of a second attribute

Tags: postgresql, select, boolean, conditional-statements, case

I have a dataset of field samples whose attributes include: a sample name, a timestamp of analysis (unique key), analysis result, date sampled, and a Boolean attribute 'rerun' that describes if the record is the result of a second analysis of the same sample.  This means that there can be multiple records with the same sample name and sample date, but in that case, the second record (rerun = TRUE) is the preferred result for the selection.

name timestamp analysisResult rerun dateSampled

I have attempted to use the CASE function, but I think I am missing something simple.  I'm trying to put it as an element of the WHERE clause, but that is not working as is.

For example, I'm trying something like:

```
    SELECT name,analysisResult
    FROM sciencyTable
    WHERE date = '12/02/11',
    AND (some working CASE function)
    ORDER BY time;
```

Any hints would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your query is to outer join against rerun samples and coalesce:

```
select
  firstruns.name
, coalesce(reruns.analysisResult, firstruns.analysisResult) as analysisResult
from
(select name, dateSampled, analysisResult
 from sciencyTable
 where not rerun
) as firstruns
left join
(select name, dateSampled, analysisResult
 from sciencyTable
 where rerun
) as reruns
using (name,dateSampled)
```

If you have multiple reruns for given name,date and want to pick the latest, you should try [windowing functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: Thank you, dbenhur, I will give that a try.  Thanks also for the link, looking at it now.  Cheers.